# Sum types on Dart

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

### What's an idiomatic way to represent sum types in OOP, more specifically in **Dart** language?

I'm building a questionnaire app on Flutter.

Say I have a **sum type** data structure in a functional language like this:

```
data AnswerSpec =   Boolean
                    | ChooseOne [Text]
                    | ChooseOneWithOpen [Text]
                    | ChooseMany [Text]
                    | ChooseManyWithOpen [Text]
                    | Open
                    | Duration
                    | SleepDuration
                    | Datetime -- date + time
                    | Count
```

This defines the question's accepted answer type/choice. Each question has only one of those associated with it.

Ideally, I'd also like to **associate the given answer with the same entity**, because I need to validate (build validation methods) that the given answer adheres to the accepted answer choice.

### Example

- **Question:** *Which part of your body did you exercise today?*
- **Accepted Answer type:** `ChooseMany ["Upper body", "Lower body"]` (*the user can choose both*)
- **User's answer:** `["Upper body"]`

As you can see, the answer itself may be of type `int`, `string`, `List<string>`, `DateTime` or even a combination of those, such as `List<string>` + `string`.

### Can you help me understand what's the best way to model this on Dart, with its inheritance abstractions like `class`, `abstract class` and `mixin`?

Comment: Dart doesn't have such feature. You have to implement something on your own

Comment: I'm aware. I'm asking **how**.

Comment: That's the point. There is no idiomatic way of doing it. You have to make up your own. For what it's worth, I've made one: https://github.com/rrousselgit/union

Comment: I see yeah. Your lib looks solid but unfortunately, it doesn't extend to accommodate an open amount of options which is essentially what I need.

But give me some rope here; considering what I outlined above, would you put all options + answer under one base class, or one abstract class from which they all inherit? I feel silly putting all possible answer types in one abstract base class when each question can only take one specific one.